# SQL query doesn't return multiple rows per matched item in a join

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I have 2 tables:

```
mysql> describe solution_sections;
+---------------------+---------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field               | Type          | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+---------------------+---------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| solution_section_id | int(10)       | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| display_order       | int(10)       | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| section_name        | varchar(1000) | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
+---------------------+---------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
3 rows in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> describe suggested_solution_comments;

+-----------------------+----------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field                 | Type           | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+-----------------------+----------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| comment_id            | int(10)        | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| problem_id            | int(10)        | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| suggested_solution_id | int(10)        | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| commenter_id          | int(10)        | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| comment               | varchar(10000) | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| solution_part         | int(3)         | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| date                  | date           | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
+-----------------------+----------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
```

What I am trying to do is to display the list of section_name from the solution_sections table, and n matched items from the suggested_solution_comments table for every section_name. So for every section name, the query should get the list of suggested_solution_comments associated with it.

The tables are linked by suggested_solution_comments.solution_part and solution_sections.solution_section_id

Here is what I am trying so far:

```
select section_name , comment , solution_part , display_order from solution_sections 
    left join suggested_solution_comments on 
    solution_sections.solution_section_id = suggested_solution_comments.solution_part   
    where suggested_solution_id = 188 OR suggested_solution_id IS NULL
    group by display_order;
```

The problem is that the query gets the list of section_name, and one matched comment per section_name, but not more than one comment.  Any idea why it doesn't get all the associated comments?

Thanks!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the `GROUP BY` might account for what you are seeing try without it (UPDATE as per comments)

```
select section_name , comment , solution_part , display_order 
from solution_sections 
left join suggested_solution_comments on 
solution_sections.solution_section_id = suggested_solution_comments.solution_part   
where suggested_solution_id = 188 OR suggested_solution_id IS NULL
order by display_order;
```

Some remarks:

You datamodel seems a bit strange... for example the `solution_part` is `int(3)` and is linked to `solution_section_id` which is turn is an `autoincrement int(10)` ?

Comment: It worked to get more than one comment, but for some reason, it is diplaying the items in somewhat random order :) Is there a way to get the items to display according to the order of the section_name in the table?

Comment: @GeekedOut try with the update above... if that doesn't work: what do mean by "order of the section_name in the table" ? alphabetical ?

Comment: I mean more as they are listed in the database.  I guess by their id, which is record_id that I didn't even bother to list in the select clause.  I'll give that a try here and let you know how it goes :) By the way, what effect does it have when you listed 4 columns together in the order by clause?  What does that achieve?

Comment: @GeekedOut that tells the Db that you want them ordered by the first column listed... in case there are more than one row with the same value in that column it should further sort by the next column etc.